# How to refresh a list straight away when the data in the list is deleted?

Tags: swiftui

I have a question about SwiftUI.

I am struggling to delete the items in the list and display the empty list once the delete button is tapped.

As shown in the pic, the items stay there. However, when I move to another view and come back, the items are gone. I want to make this happen without moving to another view.

```swift
// Delete Button
 Button(action: {
        do { try context.delete(model: DisplayedWordsObject.self)} 
catch { print("Failed to clear all Country and City data.")}}) 
{Text("Delete") }

// The List to be deleted once the button is tapped 
List(uniqueWords.sorted()) { unique in
    HStack {
        Text("\(unique.wordID)")
        Text("\(unique.word)")
        Text(": \(unique.meaning1)")}}
                 .id(UUID())
                 .onAppear {
                     Array(Set(playerInfos)).forEach { playerInfo in
                        Array(Set(playerInfo.correctWords)).forEach { index in
                             if index < displayedWord.count {
                                 if !uniqueWords.contains(where: {$0 == displayedWord[index]}) 
                                     { uniqueWords.append(displayedWord[index]) }}}
```

[image: List Picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve what you want.

Looking at your previous code with another account that you used,
try the following example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
     // @Environment(\.context) private var context
     // ... 
     @Query var playerInfos: [PlayerInfo1]

    let displayedWord: [Word] = [
        Word(word: "Arvo", meaning1: "午後", meaning2: "午前"),
        Word(word: "Bin", meaning1: "ゴミ箱", meaning2: "壺"),
        Word(word: "Runners", meaning1: "スニーカー", meaning2: "走る人"),
        Word(word: "Arvo", meaning1: "午後", meaning2: "午前"),
        Word(word: "Bin", meaning1: "ゴミ箱", meaning2: "壺"),
        Word(word: "Runners", meaning1: "スニーカー", meaning2: "走る人")]
    
    @State private var uniqueWords: [Word] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Delete") {
            do {
                try context.delete(model: DisplayedWordsObject.self)
                getUniqueWords() // <--- here
            }
            catch {
                print("Failed to clear all Country and City data \(error)")
            }
        }
        List(uniqueWords.sorted()) { unique in
            HStack {
                Text("\(unique.wordID)")
                Text("\(unique.word)")
                Text(": \(unique.meaning1)")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            getUniqueWords() // <--- here
        }
    }

    // --- here
    func getUniqueWords() {
        uniqueWords.removeAll()
        Array(Set(playerInfos)).forEach { playerInfo in
            Array(Set(playerInfo.correctWords)).forEach { index in
                if index < displayedWord.count {
                    if !uniqueWords.contains(where: {$0 == displayedWord[index]}) {
                        uniqueWords.append(displayedWord[index])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```